# Get the size of a picture

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I currently have a PowerPoint macro which inserts a picture in the current slide with its original size:

```
Sub Insert_Traverse_2()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec\newpic.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

How do I 'get' the size of the image? I want to do something similar to what is described in

[Powerpoint VBA Macro to copy object's size and location and paste to another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620257/powerpoint-vba-macro-to-copy-objects-size-and-location-and-paste-to-another-obj)

but "ShapeRange" doesn't seem to be selectable for the object I created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Insert_Traverse_2()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec\newpic.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
    With oPic
        MsgBox .Width
        MsgBox .Height
        MsgBox .Left
        MsgBox .Top
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Simpler than I thought! Thanks for the answer.