# Powerpoint VBA Macro to resize all objects selected to the biggest object

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**Background**

I add an add-in that did the following thing:
For all the powerpoint objects selected (example 4 rectangles), the add-in would resize all objects height and width to match the height and width of the biggest object in the selection.

I tried to write a VBA macro to copy this add-in but nothing happens (adapting the code found in the following question: [Powerpoint VBA Macro to copy object's size and location and paste to another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620257/powerpoint-vba-macro-to-copy-objects-size-and-location-and-paste-to-another-obj)):

```
Sub test()
    Dim w As Double
    Dim h As Double
    Dim obj As Shape

    w = 0
    h = 0

    For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
        Set obj = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)
        If obj.Width > w Then
            w = obj.Width
        Else
            obj.Width = w
        End If

        If obj.Height > h Then
            h = obj.Height
        Else
            obj.Height = h
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Question**

Any idea on how to make this code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, here is a code that works (not sure if it is a really efficient one because I am new to VBA):

```
Sub resizeAll()
    Dim w As Double
    Dim h As Double
    Dim obj As Shape

    w = 0
    h = 0

    ' Loop through all objects selected to assign the biggest width and height to w and h
    For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
        Set obj = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)
        If obj.Width > w Then
            w = obj.Width
        End If

        If obj.Height > h Then
            h = obj.Height
        End If
    Next

    ' Loop through all objects selected to resize them if their height or width is smaller than h/w
    For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
        Set obj = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)
        If obj.Width < w Then
            obj.Width = w
        End If

        If obj.Height < h Then
            obj.Height = h
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There are probably a few minor tweaks you could apply to make this more efficient *in theory*.  In practice, it's unlikely you'd ever see the difference, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! (and I used your add-in explanation to add this macro to my ppt).